# Override themes functions

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

In my theme there is a functions-template.php file with a lot of functions. One of them echoes the category description on the site.

```
 function woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() {
if ( is_tax( array( 'product_cat', 'product_tag' ) ) && get_query_var( 'paged' ) == 0 ) {
    global $wp_query;

    $cat          = $wp_query->get_queried_object();
    $thumbnail_id = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $cat->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true );
    $image        = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $thumbnail_id, 'full' );

    $description = apply_filters( 'the_content', term_description() );

    if ( $image && yit_get_option( 'shop-category-image' ) == 1 ) {
        echo '<div class="term-header-image"><img src="' . $image[0] . '" width="' . $image[1] . '" height="' . $image[1] . '" alt="' . $cat->name . '" /></div>';
    }

    if ( $description ) {
        echo '<div class="term-description">' . $description . '</div>';
    }
}
}
```

I want to echo another variable instead without messing with the files. Is there a way to "override" an existing function?

I've been fiddling a bit with mu-plugins etc but with no success.
I always get the `Fatal error: Cannot redeclare woocommerce_taxonomy_archive_description() (previously declared in` error when adding the same function in my custom functions file..

Comment: What you need is called Child Theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it can be overridden from a child theme.  You can override the function from your child themes functions.php file.

See more about child theme https://codex.wordpress.org/Child_Themes

WordPress loads child theme first and then the parent theme. So if you create a function with same name in your child theme, then the if condition with `! function_exists` will will be false and hence there this function won't be declared.

If you want to override from a plugin then you've to declare the function in earlier execution. Try declaring it in a init hook.

```
    add_action('init', 'theme_func_override', 5);
    function theme_func_override(){
        function override_func(){
            //code goes here
        }
    }
```

**Update**

If the function isn't declared with `function_exists()` check within a if condition then you can't override it!

Comment: Sorry, wasn't clear enough.. I use a child theme, but,i want to develop a plugin that i can install on several sites with certain functions without the need to edit any files, even child theme files. I'm not sure if it's even possible :-)

Comment: Oh no, i'm so stupid/tired!! I provided wrong function in my question. I updated with the right code. I'm really sorry for that!! Will your code still do the job? What shall i put in "//code goes here!"? I'm still learning :) Thanks friend!

Comment: ok:) So if the `function_exists() ` don't exists in the function i provided in the question, then it's not possible to override it?!

Comment: Yes, it can't  be override then.